# Binding Image ImageSource to URL breaks HttpClient NTLM Handshake

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, ntlm, dotnet-httpclient

I have a .NET 4.5 WPF application which displays a number of icons in a grid - those icons are loaded through setting the ImageSource of an Image control to a specific URL (no authentication necessary). Additionally, there is a button which can be pressed to retrieve some data from an internal web service which is secured with windows authentication (NTLM, not Kerberos) via HttpClient.

I've noticed some exceedingly strange behaviour with this setup. If I leave it as is, when the button is pressed, the NTLM handshake will actually fail after the first step (client will send request and receive 401, then refuses to send again with auth headers). However, if I change the ImageSource to bind to nothing, or to a local file, or create the ImageSource manually by downloading the file with the HttpClient in the background, the NTLM handshake completes as normal.

This seems to happen with any NTLM site, and any site hosting an image. Has anyone experienced this before?

Here's an example of this happening in a test app I threw together.
Viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public ICommand DownloadData { get; set; }


    public ViewModel()
    {
        DownloadData = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                using(var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials })
                using (
                    var client = new HttpClient(handler)
                        {
                            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://somentlmservice.com")
                        })
                {
                       var data = client.GetAsync("/someresource").Result
                }

            });


        Image = "http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg";
    }
}
```

And view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="60" Width="60" />
        <Button Command="{Binding DownloadData}">Test</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic question, but where did you first learn the technique of using httpClientHandler and httpClient in a Using block?  I believe this to be an anti-pattern with HttpClient and I'm trying to find the source of the practice.  Thx.  Sorry I can't help with your question!

Comment: No worries - I didn't pick up the pattern from anywhere, all I saw was that they're both disposable so I figured I may as well get rid of them for this test app. It also proves that whatever the bug is, it's not related to a particular instance of HttpClient.

Comment: I suspect that the IDisposable interface is the motivator for many people.  The problem is that you lose many benefits of HttpClient by throwing it away, plus it forcibly closes the TCP connection, removing the benefit of Http 1.1's persistent connections.

Comment: Huh, that's a good point, hadn't considered that! Thanks!